# How can I modify an ObjC method's parameters within a block?

Tags: objective-c, block

If I have an Objective-C method that takes an object parameter, and said method uses a block to do its work internally, is there a way to modify that object from within the block?

It is my understanding that blocks capture variables from their parent scope by referring to them within the block, and that they are copied by default. And if I want to be able to modify rather than work with a copy of a surrounding object, I can prefix its declaration with `__block`, but I'm unable to do so with method parameters since I didn't declare it myself, right?

For example:

```
- (void)doWorkWithString:(NSString *)someString
{
    [NSFoo doAwesomeClassMethodWithBlock:^{
        // How can I modify someString here directly?
        // By just changing someString, I'm changing the captured copy
    }];
}
```

Comment: I'm too lazy to look up the docs, but I don't believe captured variables to a block are copied; that would be very surprising since objects may not implement copy. If __block is not specified, then the objects will be retained by the block though. Inside the block, object pointers are no different than anywhere else so to answer your question you can modify them any way you like.  What you can't do is write to a variable that has been captured *IF* __block was not supplied.  Variables marked with __block are not retained by the block so be careful of that. Hopefully that makes some sense.

Comment: @darren: non-__block variables to a block *are* copied. But a variable's value is never an object. You can only have an *object pointer*. So, yes, when a block captures an object pointer, it copies the pointer. This has absolutely nothing to do with copying of objects.

Comment: I meant "object pointer" parameter when I said "object parameter". e.g. Passing an NSString * instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say about capture is correct; what you probably want to do is supply the objects that should be the subject of the block as arguments to it — much like if you were calling a C function. So e.g.

```
void (^ someBlock)(NSString *) =
    ^(NSString *someString)
    {
        NSLog(@"length is %d", [someString length]);
    };

...

someBlock(@"String 1");
someBlock(@"A second string");
```

Answer (score 2):

"that takes an object parameter"

First of all, you are almost certainly confused by the fact that you cannot have a parameter or variable of object type. You can only have pointers to objects. So yes, non-`__block` variables that are captured by a block are copied by the block. But the variables here are either primitives or object pointers, not "objects".

If you only need to mutate the object that an object pointer points to, and that does not involve changing the pointer to point to another object, then you are not changing the variable. And since you are not changing the variable, all this "copying the variable" and `__block` stuff is completely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my comment above was incredibly confusing. Hopefully the following clears up what I was trying to say:

```
- (void)yourMethod:(Foo *)parameterFoo
{
    __block Foo *blockVariable = [Foo someFoo];
    Foo *capturedVariable = [Foo anotherFoo];

    void(^doWorkBlock)(Foo *bp) = ^(Foo *bp){
        // If your block accesses a scoped variable that is not marked with __block, it will
        // retain it, so here capturedVariable and bp would be retained by the block
        capturedVariable.aProperty = 5.0;
        bp.aProperty = 10.0;

        // As you can see, you can modify the objects all you like.        
        // What you cannot do is assign something to capturedVariable or bp because they
        // were not marked as __block
        // WONT WORK
        capturedVariable = [Foo new];

        // However, you can write to blockVariable because it is marked as __block
        // WORKS
        blockVariable = [Foo new];
        // Remember, though that the block will not retain this variable itself because
        // of the __block 
    };

    // Note, it's weird for the block to take a parameter since it could just access the
    // variable directly.  This just serves to show how a block would handle a parameter.
    doWorkBlock(parameterFoo);
}
```